# Is it impossible to run mount(1) from a setuid program?

Tags: mount, root, setuid

I have a setuid program which, among other things, needs to remount a normally-readonly disk so it can write to it.  That is, the program wants to run the command

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

But the `mount` command is itself setuid, and its check to see if it's being run by root looks at the *real* user id, so it fails if it's run from a setuid program, saying "only root can use the remount option" or something like that.

Is there really no way for a setuid program to run the `mount` commnd?

Answer (score 2):

Just as I was posting my question, I figured out the answer.
A simple call to

```
setuid(geteuid())
```

right before the `exec()` of `/bin/mount` was all it took.